# JQuery Drag & Drop How to swap already dragged with newly dragged item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a set of divs that can be dragged on another set of div's. Hear is the code

```
    $('#mapColumns div').draggable({
          containment: '#content',
          cursor: 'move',
          revert: 'invalid',
          stack:'#mapRow div'
    });
    alert($('#mapRow div'));

    $('#mapRow div').droppable({
        accept: '#mapColumns div',
        drop: handleColumnDrop
    });
```

What I want to do is if a div is dragged on a droppable div which already has a previously dragged div placed on it then I want to revert the previously  dragged div to its original position and the newly dragged to take its place. How do I achieve this.

The problem is I am not able to get handle on div which is already dragged on droppable element

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want!

Here is a quick demo and this is for demo purpose and you can beautify it if you want

http://jsfiddle.net/N4xWr/21/